# Specific nuxt-child rather than slug?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Suppose I want to make a blog.

in /pages/ I would add

```
pages/
-- blog/
--+-- _artcile.vue
--+-- index.vue
-- blog.vue
```

which would let me have a route /blog and /blog/:article?. Most such examples I have found in these cases, (e.g. in the Nuxt docs for user and user_id) the content which is being requests is standard (e.g. user id or markdown file for the blog). But what if I want each entry to be a unique component? e.g.

```
pages/
-- blog/
--+-- custom_article_1.vue
--+-- custom_article_2.vue
--+-- index.vue
-- blog.vue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create `_artcile.vue` and inside it determine yourself what component you want using :is. [Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components)

```
<component v-bind:is="currentTabComponent"></component>
```

Comment: true, I have done that in the past, but I was hoping for a nuxt inspired way to handle only specific nested routes... if that makes sense